# How to determine optimal file size for merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, sorting, mergesort

Most of you will realize this, but to me it came a bit as a surprise: it's way faster to sort (for example) 96 files each size 4Mb than 6 files of 64Mb using mergesort (holding the total amount of information constant). I stumbled upon this finding by accident. So this begs the question, what is the optimal input file size for a mergesort?

I assume that there will be a curvi-linear shaped relationship between sorting time (y axis) and number of files (x axis). Is there an algorithm, is it more rule of thumb or just trying a couple of different file sizes? Obvious factors that will impact this are:
* max number of files that OS can open simultaneously.
* read / write speed of harddisk

Any references are welcome!

Comment: How much is "way faster"? Have you accounted for the time difference needed to read the files in your measurements (you'll likely need a bigger read buffer for the 64MB files, and the larger files are more likely to be fragmented)?

Comment: Way waster means: sorting takes 25 minutes with the small files did not finish after an hour using the large files, so it's at least 2x times as slow.

Comment: What algorithm are you using? Is this a multi-way merge or do you perform some sequence of 2-way merge steps? In general, external sorting is mostly bound by IO not processing overhead. But your numbers are *way* too low either way. What platform/language are you using? On a modern machine and using a compiled language, sorting 400MB of data should take seconds not minutes (and certainly not hours), and it should be mostly IO-bound.

Comment: I using Ubuntu 10.10, Quad Core processor, 8Gb and I am using (probably) a naive implementation in Python based on http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Merge_sort#Python (see Full Implementation)

Comment: Files of 1 byte. Then it becomes a no-op operation. Really, your question isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sorting involves moving files, then the conventional measures for "fastest" sort algorithm don't really apply. For moving files around, a faster sort algorithm will consist of minimizing the number of file writes.

Selection sort can be used and has very close to the minimum number of swaps possible, but again, in the worst case, each file has to be written twice: Once when it's swapped out of the way to make place for the file that belongs there, and once swapped into the place it's supposed to be when its time comes.

There is an algorithm which performs at most n+1 assignments. A 'swap' (which is what most sorting algorithms use) involves three assignments, (using a temp variable). This works pretty much by doing a selection sort without actually swapping anything. By either writing each selected item to new memory, or saving the sort order in memory and then reorganizing files in the same memory space after the fact (defragmentation style). This algorithm would really be minimal in terms of data copying. This is ideal when copying items is expensive (sorting data on disk).